# Orion Subscription to update entity attributes from CrateDB, on value changes

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Is there a convenient way to subscribe to update an attribute, each time another attribute changes?

I have this entity on Orion:

```
{
  "id": "Asset:001",
  "type": "SomeType",
  "Input": {
    "type": "Text",
    "value": "State",
    "metadata": {}
  },
  "Output": {
    "type": "Float",
    "value": null,
    "metadata": {}
  }
}
```

I subscribe to notify value changes to Quantumleap:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -X POST \
    'http://orion:1026/v2/subscriptions/' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{
  "description": "Orion notify Quantumleap on State changhes",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": ".*",
        "type": "Sometype"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "state"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "State"
    ],
    "metadata": []
  }
}'
```

And I got my data on `CrateDB` where I made some calculation.
Then I would like to get the results of this computing, and put back as an attribute to the entity `Asset:001`.

Now I get this done by a script, but it would be nice to achieve the same result with a subscription, is this possible?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The attributes in `attrs` within `notification` are the ones to be included in the notification. The attributes in `attrs` within `condition` are the ones which change trigger the notification.

You can use a different set of attributes in each array, so the use case you describe in covered.

For instance, changes in attribute `A` will notify the value of attribute `B` using something like this:

```
{
  ...
  "subject": {
    ...
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "A"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    ...
    "attrs": [
      "B"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the indication, did you have any hint on how to include the payload from CrateDB answer?

Comment: Note that from the point of view of Orion, the payload in the response of the notification endpoint is pretty useless. Orion only needs to know if the notification has been delivered. To that end, there are some fields in the subscription payload about it, the ones that start with "last" described at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md#subscriptionnotification

Comment: `failsCounter` and `timesSent` also provide interesting feedback about notification delivery

Comment: The payload I am referring to is not that of the subscription endpoint, but the one coming from CrateDB.
I would like to get data from the database, and put back as attributes value to the entity.
I should nest an http request to the database, in the subscription provisioning, but I can't figure how to achieve that.

Comment: I was reading about registration, and providing an endpoint who respond with the data from the DB, I can then place a subscription to that endpoint, and get the data sync. Is this the only way?

Comment: Maybe it would be better for the sake of clarity to ask that as a new question, please.